# How to show detail info in the "Extended Detail" panel of Leaks?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm checking my app with Leaks and find some memory leaks indeed.
But In the "Extended Detail" panel, I can't locate the source code directly.
There are only memory address where the leaks happens.

Here is the snapshot:
[image]

And here is the snapshot from others:
[image]

I have been looking for infomation by google, but no result.
Who can help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you double click the red thick line of memory leak as shown  above , in the lower portion of the Instrument you will be able to see all the leaks and related info. If u want to find detailed info about a particular leak just click the arrow which comes up in its address field.
   This will refresh the window and tell you the details with  Responsible Caller column in the end of the table , it gives the specific method  name where the leaks has occurred. If you double click the row, it will open that corresponding .m file where that method has been implemented.

This link will be helpful for you.
http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/04/how-to-check-memory-leaks-in-xcode-4.html